# XMPP MUC problem

Tags: javascript, xmpp, strophe

I am using `XMPP` with strope.js and openfire. I have a query that how to get all the members already present in the room???

**More Priece:**
When i refresh the page and send my presence stanza to the room. I get my presence from the room and i show room joined. But how to get the `presence stanza` of whole those who are already in the room.

**EDIT:**

Let me explain you by case, Suppose A and B wants to group chat. First A enters the Room and he sees himself in the room. Then B enters the room, so A gets presence stanza of B and now on A side there are A and B in the room. But on B side it shows only B in the room.

Now A refreshes the page and B gets the presence stanza and now on B side both are in the room, but on A side now only A is in the room.

Comment: Per XMPP spec, server must send back presences from all existing occupants' room JIDs to the new occupant. (http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#enter-pres) It may not come back immediately with your own presence "echo", but you probably will get it a request or 2 later.

Are you sure you joined the room succcessfully? Are the messages you sent to the room received by other occupants?

Keep in mind: Server will only send back other occupants' room JIDs, not their server full JIDs.

Comment: Ya i have successfully joined the room. And the messages are also received by other occupants. The problem is when i am in the room and other occupant come in then i get the presence, but when i refresh i stay alone in the room.

Comment: When refreshing, are you using the same SID to reconnect? Or are you re-connecting to Jabber using a new connection?

Comment: When you refresh, do you sign out from the server? Or you just re-connected by re-using the same SID?

If you never sign out from the server, it's likely that the server thought you're still in the room, and sending another presence message to the room only updates your status. (http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0045.html#changepres) If possible, try leaving and rejoining the room again.

Or, since you're always saving the SID somewhere, maybe you can save the room's roster as well...?

Comment: @Jimy - Could you show the XMPP transactions? Is the MUC configured to have presence broadcasted back to its members? (I believe this is the default configuration for all MUCs.) After A refreshes, have you tried to leave and rejoin the room to see if B's presence got echo'ed back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The presence is sent by Openfire to all occupants in the room, just add an event handler in strophe to the presence stanza. Also when a new member joins the room, her presence is broadcasted to all members already in the room by the room itself.

Also another way to get all users in the room is to query for roster of the room

Hope this helps